# Manipulate kafka stream from a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have a postgres table and connected it to Kafk using debezium connector. Now I want to edit the message (adding one custom column) in the kafka topic (postgres table data) and convert it as a stream to create a KSQLDB table.

I do not want to write code. I need to achieve it within KSQLDB. Help me to achieve it. Any blogs or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I added the custom column using the `transform` also I need this custom column to be present in the key of the kafka topic that was also achieved by this `transform`. So my source is below, may be helpful for someone,

```
{
  "name": "ksqldb-connector-kafkaetl",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "database.hostname": "ipaddress",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "user",
    "database.password": "pwd",
    "database.dbname": "practice_1_kafkaetl",
    "database.server.name": "postgres",
    "topic.prefix":"etlsource.prc1",
    "table.include.list": "dbo.table1",
    "column.include.list":"dbo.table1.col1,dbo.table1.col2,dbo.table1.col3,dbo.table1.col4",
    "slot.name" : "slot_batch_work_items",
    "transforms": "unwrap,InsertSource",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false",
    "transforms.InsertSource.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Key",
    "transforms.InsertSource.static.field":"pactice_id",
    "transforms.InsertSource.static.value":"1"
  }
}
```